# Windows API structure field equivalent in .Net class library?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, managed

To avoid writting unnecessary P/Invokes, I would like to know whether the `lpMinimumApplicationAddress` and `lpMaximumApplicationAddress` fields of the [**SYSTEM_INFO**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure are exposed in a managed way somewhere in the .Net framework class library.

> lpMinimumApplicationAddress
>
> A pointer to the lowest memory address accessible to applications and dynamic-link libraries (DLLs).
>
> lpMaximumApplicationAddress
>
> A pointer to the highest memory address accessible to applications and DLLs.

I think maybe its possibly, because the .Net Framework class library contains various classes related to system information, but I didn't found those values.

Comment: You want to know if there is an equivalent of the two fields, or what data type they should have?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman An equivalent of the two fields, I mean like for example some equivalents of other members of the same struct, or other WinAPI definitions, which can be found in the `System.Environment` or `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` classes. Thanks for comment.

Comment: I don't think there is, this is a very specific *Windows* call, not related to the .NET framework which tries to abstract these things away.

Comment: Seems there is, as described here as properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227579%28v=vs.60%29.aspx however I'm not sure at which assembly or namespace reffers that documentation. I found more docs on MSDN about one **SystemInfo** class in **Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware** and another **SystemInfo** class in **Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity**, those aren't.

Comment: You are referencing 18 year old documentation of VBA...

Comment: The other reference is to Windows CE documentation. A little more recent, but replaced for a few years already too.

Comment: My fault I didn't noticed the VBA title on the breadcrumb

Comment: What could you do with the information that would not involve p/invokes?

Comment: @David Heffernan Is for scan the process memory of a 3rd party process, which strictlly requires other additional P/Invokes to use those fields, but I just wanted to know If I could ignore the required **SYSTEM_INFO** definition to at least use those fields as managed equivalents, just for curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .net framework library classes do not expose this information.